# link to image location in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, image, hyperlink, directory

i am using xmlwriter in c# to create an xml file that holds records for club members. 
i want to store with the record of each member a link to the location of the individuals id photo that will be stored in a folder.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string documentPath = @"D:\Book6.xml";
        XmlDocument myxDoc = new XmlDocument();
        myxDoc.Load(documentPath);
        //Member Node creation 

                    XmlNode member = myxDoc.CreateElement("Member");
                    //XmlNode information = myxDoc.CreateElement("Information");
                    XmlNode name = myxDoc.CreateElement("Name");
                    name.InnerText = txtName.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(name);
                    //
                    XmlNode dateofbirth = myxDoc.CreateElement("DateofBirth");
                    dateofbirth.InnerText = txtDOB.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(dateofbirth);
                    //
                    XmlNode idnumber = myxDoc.CreateElement("IdNumber");
                    idnumber.InnerText = txtID.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(idnumber);
                    //
                    XmlNode address = myxDoc.CreateElement("Address");
                    address.InnerText = txtAddress1.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(address);
                    //
                    XmlNode contactnumber = myxDoc.CreateElement("ContactNumber");
                    contactnumber.InnerText = txtCellnumber.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(contactnumber);
                    //
                    XmlNode email = myxDoc.CreateElement("Email");
                    email.InnerText = txtEmail.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(email);
                    //
                    XmlNode designation = myxDoc.CreateElement("Designation");
                    designation.InnerText = txtDesignation.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(designation);
                    //
                    XmlNode branch = myxDoc.CreateElement("Branch");
                    branch.InnerText = txtBranch.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(branch);
                    //
                    XmlNode province = myxDoc.CreateElement("Province");
                    province.InnerText = txtProvince.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(province);
                    //
                    XmlNode district = myxDoc.CreateElement("District");
                    district.InnerText = txtDistrict.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(district);
                    //
                    XmlNode constituency = myxDoc.CreateElement("Constituency");
                    constituency.InnerText = txtConstituency.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(constituency);
                    //
                    XmlNode formnumber = myxDoc.CreateElement("FormNumber");
                    formnumber.InnerText = txtFormNum.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(formnumber);
                    //
                    XmlNode subscription = myxDoc.CreateElement("Subscription");
                    subscription.InnerText = txtSubscripton.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(subscription);
                    //
                    XmlNode period = myxDoc.CreateElement("Period");
                    period.InnerText = txtPeriod.Text;
                    member.AppendChild(period);
                    //    
                    XmlNode image = myxDoc.CreateElement("Image");
                    image.InnerText = txtName.Text;//imageLocation; //imagePhoto.ToString();
                    member.AppendChild(image);

            //member.AppendChild(information);


            myxDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(member);             
            myxDoc.Save(documentPath);
            txtName.Text = String.Empty;
            txtDOB.Text = String.Empty;
            txtID.Text = String.Empty;
            txtAddress1.Text = String.Empty;
            txtAddress2.Text = String.Empty;
            txtAddress3.Text = String.Empty;
            txtCellnumber.Text = String.Empty;
            txtEmail.Text = String.Empty;
            txtDesignation.Text = String.Empty;
            txtBranch.Text = String.Empty;
            txtProvince.Text = String.Empty;
            txtDistrict.Text = String.Empty;
            txtConstituency.Text = String.Empty;
            txtFormNum.Text = String.Empty;
            txtSubscripton.Text = String.Empty;
            txtPeriod.Text = String.Empty;
            txtWard.Text = String.Empty;

     }

   private void btnPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


       OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
       //filters
       open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
       if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           imagePhoto.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
           imagePhoto.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                          imageLocation = open.FileName;
       } 
   } 
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or just telling us what you doing?

Comment: sorry, yes the problem is how do i make the file location open as a link when i open the xml file in excel

Comment: @leppie yes i need help in how to make it a link so that when i open the xml in excel it is an active link that works

Answer (score 0):

After looking at importing data for a little bit I found that it seems to only import data as a pure string. I even explored using the "=HYPERLINK()" function however it gets imported as text and does not get calculated.

There are a few possible solutions depending on your needs.

Option 1:
You could create an excel file rather than an xml file. However this is complicated and can be a little fiddly.

Option 1.1: You could create and excel xml file. You can see how these are laid out by saving a sheet as xml and then looking at the xml and writing some code to re create it.

Option 2:
If you are the person who is going to import the data into the excel file then you could run a macro or vb script through a selection of data to convert it to links.

Comment: i agree option 1 is indeed a mess to implement, i am new at coding that was what i tried, but decided to put it on hold until i got my requirements working

Comment: option 2 looks like something i can explore for now thank you